# Flutter Hooks: Getting error while using useEffect with TextEditingController

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-hooks

I want to use useEffect with TextEditingController instead of useTextEditingController.

Error: late Initialization Error. Am I not writing init and disposing correctly?

```
class EffectTest extends HookWidget {
  const EffectTest({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    late TextEditingController controller;

    useEffect(
      () {
        controller = TextEditingController();

        return () {
          controller.clear();
        };
      },
      [],
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text(controller.value.text),
            TextField(
              controller: controller,
              onSubmitted: (value) {
                print(controller.value.text);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include full widget

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, Please check now

Comment: It is working fine on chrome test, Can you recheck

Comment: On Android, it starts and stays for 1 second and then - LateInitializationError: Local 'controller' has not been initialized.

Comment: useEffect is used to update, you dont want to assign new controller every time, better use `useTextEditingController`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, What exactly is the use of useEffect? Can I not use it as a replacement for Init and dispose state lifecycles?

Comment: you can check [it](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_hooks/latest/flutter_hooks/useEffect.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
final TextEditingController controller = useTextEditingController();
```

flutter hooks will handle everything, you do not have to initialize it in useEffect.